# Why should I use JSON.stringify() inside the STOMP send() method?

Tags: spring, websocket

I'm trying to figure out how to write a simple chat on spring and Websocket.
I have simple configuration class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/hello").withSockJS();
    }

}
```

and class controller ike this :

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {


    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(3000); // simulated delay
        return new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName() + "!");
    }

}
```

I understand that he gets requests via **app/hello**, but I don't understand why i have to use  `JSON.stringify({ 'name': name })`call inside a js script?:

```
...

function sendName() {
            var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
            stompClient.send("/app/hello", {}, JSON.stringify({ 'name': name }));
        }
...
```

That is, this function creates json and passes it to a function that performs deserialization, as I understand it, but can we do without it? or is it an obligatory condition?

**Greeting class**:

```
public class Greeting {

    private String content;

    public Greeting(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

}
```

**HelloMessage class**:

```
public class HelloMessage {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is it obligatory? Why don't you try without it and see what happens?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I understand that nothing will be recorded, so I ask what is going on

Comment: I don't know what you mean. If it doesn't work without it, doesn't that tell you that it's obligatory? If you want to know what it _does_, read e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify (it doesn't "create JSON", it creates a _string_).

Comment: @jonrsharpe but it says : "A JSON string representing the given value, or undefined."